# Memory address 32-bit

Tags: memory, ddr

I'm working with a Zedboard and I'm printing to the screen memory addresses of consecutive 32-bit float numbers.

So the print generates this:

```
Result 0: 5374.557617
Memory is A000000
Result 1: 5474.651233
Memory is A000004
Result 2: 5574.557129
Memory is A000008
 ....
```

So memory is incremented 4 each time.I can't understand why a memory with 4 more bits can keep a 32 bit number. The only way this makes sense is is hexadecimal is convertible to bytes and so +4 bytes=+32 bits.

However this isn't the way I learned, everyone says that hexadecimal shall me converted to bits

Surprisingly I haven't found anything on the Internet about this question in particular.

Comment: RAM is very, very, very rarely addressed in such a way as to specify *bit* addresses. *Byte* addresses are the norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So memory is incremented 4 each time.

Nope. The *address* is incremented by 4. RAM Memory is typically addressed byte-wise, that means there is one byte of data at each address.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. Just to clarify, when I increment the address like this:
0x40400000 + 0x58

am I incrementing 58 bytes?

Comment: Nope, you are incrementing by 88 Bytes. Remember that `0x` is hex prefix.

Comment: Oh ok. So if i do 0x40400000 + 58 i'll be incrementing 58 bytes but if I do 0x40400000 + 0x58 i'll be incrementing (58)_16=(88)_10 bytes. Correct?